# Unix sed output coming pattern twice in replace

Tags: sed, xml

I've an XML file `logback-spring.xml`.

Now, I want to replace string `DEBUG` with `TRACE`, wherever `ref="logstash"` occurs *only in the next line*.

The input file looks like below:

```
  <logger name="com.abcd.tdi" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="logstash"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Async-Appender"/>
    </logger>

  <springProfile name="dev">
        <logger name="com.abcd.tdi" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="logstash"/>
        </logger>
  <springProfile name="dev">
        <logger name="com.abcd.tdi" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>
```

While using `sed` command I'm getting output *twice* in the replacement.

I have used the following `sed` command:

```
sed -n -e '/ref="logstash"/!h' -e '/ref="logstash"/{H;x;s/DEBUG/TRACE/}; p; ' logback-spring.xml
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. For clarification, please edit your question to include an example of the current, unwanted output of your command. Also, as a general rule, when working with structured files like XML or JSON, using a dedicated parser (in this case e.g. `xmlstarlet`) is preferred over using general-purpose text tools like `sed` or `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

Given a well-formed XML document, like the following (modified from your example):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <springProfile name="dev">
    <logger name="com.abcd.tdi" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="logstash"/>
      <appender-ref ref="Async-Appender"/>
    </logger>
  </springProfile>
  <springProfile name="dev">
    <logger name="com.abcd.tdi" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="logstash"/>
    </logger>
  </springProfile>
  <springProfile name="dev">
    <logger name="com.abcd.tdi" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
  </springProfile>
</root>
```

you may use `xmlstarlet` to change all `level` attributes that are set to `DEBUG` to `TRACE` for each `logger` node whose `appender-ref` child node has a `ref` attribute that is `logstash`, like so:

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u '//logger[appender-ref/@ref = "logstash"]/@level[. = "DEBUG"]' -v 'TRACE' file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <springProfile name="dev">
    <logger name="com.abcd.tdi" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="logstash"/>
      <appender-ref ref="Async-Appender"/>
    </logger>
  </springProfile>
  <springProfile name="dev">
    <logger name="com.abcd.tdi" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="logstash"/>
    </logger>
  </springProfile>
  <springProfile name="dev">
    <logger name="com.abcd.tdi" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
  </springProfile>
</root>
```

An XPath query similar to [what choroba is using](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/563018/116858) would also work:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//logger[@level = "DEBUG"][appender-ref/@ref = "logstash"]/@level' -v 'TRACE' file.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML-aware tool when working with XML. For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML), you can achieve the result by

```
open logback-spring.xml ;
for //logger[@level='DEBUG'][appender-ref/@ref='logstash']
    set @level 'TRACE' ;
save :b ;
```

If your XML contains namespace declarations, the code will be a bit more complex.